# VeeValidate - check validated input field to enable another input

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Its my  first time using VeeValidate.  How  can I enable/disable a form field just when another is valid. For example, just enable password field after veevalidate checks the user field as valid.

Comment: You can keep the password input filed dynamically disabled whenever user field has an error. :disabled="error.has('nameOfUserField').

Comment: But i think this approach is not possible on vee-validate  3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap both relevant fields in a [ValidationObserver](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-observer.html#scoped-slot-props) and use it's scoped prop `errors` to tell you when the one field is invalid.  Something like this (untested):

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ errors }">
    <ValidationProvider vid="item1" rules="required">
        <input v-model="item1" />
    </ValidationProvider>
    <ValidationProvider vid="item2" rules="required">
        <input v-model="item2" :disabled="errors.item1"/>
    </ValidationProvider>
</ValidationObserver>
```